# Sublayer not permanently updating after CABasicAnimation is added

Tags: swift, cabasicanimation, cgpath

I'm writing a function to define the location and size of a highlighted area on the screen and animate changes to the area as the user clicks through a tutorial.  Specifically, the entire screen is dimmed except for this area, which is defined by the `corners()` function referenced in the function below.  The `corners()` function is working properly but the function below is not allowing the sublayer/path to permanently change to the new location after each execution of the function.  In other words, each time the function is called, the start of the animation is the original location of the path on the screen.

```
func prepareForEditing(editing:Bool) {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
        animation.duration = 0.3

        //the corners() function sets the sublayer, including the sublayer's path

        //let lastShape = corners(frame: TutorialModal.tutorialRects[tutorialItem - 2])
        let newShape = corners(frame: TutorialModal.tutorialRects[tutorialItem - 1])

        animation.fromValue =  (dimScreen.layer.sublayers?[0] as! CAShapeLayer).path
        animation.toValue = newShape.path

        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        animation.autoreverses = false


        dimScreen.layer.sublayers?[0].add(animation, forKey: nil)

}
```

I was originally using `lastShape` to make animate the cutout, however, this was resulting in the duration of the animation being ignored (i.e., instant updating of the cutout instead of animating it on the screen).  I updated the fromValue characteristic of animation to use the actual current sublayer path (from the `dimScreen` view) and now I'm having the problem described above.

I also tried completely removing and replacing `dimScreen`'s sublayer after the animation, but that clears the entire screen before reapplying the path, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/8856706/77567 and many others.-

Comment: Bravo!  I searched for this for a while and only found answers related to `fillMode` and `isRemovedOnCompletion`.  I added this line of code and the problem was fixed:  `middle.layer.sublayers?[0] = corners(frame: TutorialModal.tutorialRects[tutorialItem - 1])`.  Thanks!